# Connectors problem to generate NC Drill Files in Altium - access violation error in module OUT_Drill.dll

Tags: connector, altium

I have a problem to generate NC Drill Files in Altium. Every time that I try, I receive a message of "access violation". I have discovered that the problem is only with the connectors with holes, because when I remove it (only for test) then Altium generates the Drill Files, but without the connector's holes.

My doubt is: I don't understand why Altium shows the message of "access violation" only when I have connectors with holes on the PCB, but with SMD connectors it doesn't happen.

Besides that, if I remove the connector from the PCB and add it manually, Altium can generate the holes of connector added manually, but not the connector added automatically by itself.

I don't know if I forgot to configure something.

[image: screenshot of error message]

I use Altium Library Loader to download all the components that i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced the same issue. Then I figured out that the reason was that the component library was from the internet which is not a standard one. I solved this issue by drawing the component library manually. Can you try to draw this connector by yourself and see what happens when you add it to your project?

Comment: Ross, you was correct, the problem was in the library of the component. I've changed the component and now works fine. Thank you for your time guys,

Answer (score 1):

Does the problem happen with any connector that has through holes?

Then this looks like a bug in Altium. You'll need to contact Altium support to get help.

Does the problem only happen with this particular footprint?

Then it's probably a bug in the footprint or library file. Quickest solution is probably rebuild the footprint yourself in a new library file.